# Pytest isn't working after update to pytest 7

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.11

I installed python 3.11 and updated the `pytest` package with `pip uninstall pytest` and `pip install pytest`

I wrote a small script to test it

```
def test_pytest_0():
 RESULT_SOLL=True
 RESULT_EXTERNAL=True
 Test_STEP_INFO='MessageBox Yes NO Run / schritt nummer 2'

 print(' Test_STEP_COMMENT=MessageBox Fragt nach : ok die Antwort war : yes') 

 assert  RESULT_SOLL==RESULT_EXTERNAL 
 print(RESULT_SOLL,RESULT_EXTERNAL,Test_STEP_INFO)
def test_pytest_1():
 RESULT_SOLL=True
 RESULT_EXTERNAL=True
 Test_STEP_INFO='MessageBox Yes NO Run / schritt nummer 3'

 print(' Test_STEP_COMMENT=MessageBox Fragt nach : was ok die Antwort war : yes') 

 assert  RESULT_SOLL==RESULT_EXTERNAL 
 print(RESULT_SOLL,RESULT_EXTERNAL,Test_STEP_INFO)
```

But nothing ran and I got this output

```
PS C:\Users\hasan.edrees\Desktop\Test_Platform_Gui\Arduino_with_GUI\python> pytest test_pytest_.py
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.3, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\hasan.edrees\Desktop\Test_Platform_Gui\Arduino_with_GUI\python
collected 2 items
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\hasan.edrees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 269, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\hasan.edrees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 322, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\hasan.edrees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\hasan.edrees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\hasan.edrees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\hasan.edrees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\hasan.edrees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\hasan.edrees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 333, in pytest_collection
INTERNALERROR>     session.perform_collect()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\hasan.edrees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 667, in perform_collect
INTERNALERROR>     self.config.pluginmanager.check_pending()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\hasan.edrees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 262, in check_pending
INTERNALERROR>     raise PluginValidationError(
INTERNALERROR> pluggy._manager.PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_html_report_title' in plugin <module 'python.conftest' from 'C:\\Users\\hasan.edrees\\Desktop\\Test_Platform_Gui\\Arduino_with_GUI\\python\\conftest.py'>

================================================ no tests ran in 0.01s ================================================
PS C:\Users\hasan.edrees\Desktop\Test_Platform_Gui\Arduino_with_GUI\python>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_html_report_title'` means the hook `pytest_html_report_title` in `conftest.py` is not recognized by `pytest`.

Since you updated your Python version you also need to reinstall the `pytest-html` plugin in the new interpreter

```
pip install pytest-html
```